# SQL view with check option

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am currently studying views... but I saw there is a view type "with check option"(transact sql)... I am kindda confused what does it do... Little help please

Comment: Hint:  Look in the documentation for `CREATE VIEW`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I checked in w3schools but there's nothing there...

Comment: @GordonLinoff still i checked some other documentation and even got more confused... seems like w3schools explains it better

Comment: Here is an article explains it better http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/01/15/with-check-option-on-create-view-what-is-it-how-s-it-work-what-other-options-are-available-for-referntial-integrity-ri-part-1.aspx

Comment: @john . . . Don't trust w3schools.  The documentation is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx.  Just look for "Check Option" on that page.

Comment: some example where it can be used will be useful to understand it's concept

Answer (score 0):

It is not a view type but a view option that makes the view function as a constraint for insert/update operations.
You can insert or a record into the table through the view only if the inserted record can be retrieved by the view.
You can update a record of the table through the view only if the updated record can be retrieved by the view.

**PostgreSQL demo**

```
create table mytable (i int);
create view myview as select i from mytable where i <= 10 with check option;
```

---

```
insert into myview (i) values (1),(2),(3);
```

> 19:26:00  [INSERT - 3 rows, 0.010 secs]  Command processed ... 1
>   statement(s) executed, 3 rows affected, exec/fetch time: 0.010/0.000
>   sec  [1 successful, 0 errors]

```
insert into myview (i) values (11);
```

> 19:26:20  [INSERT - 0 rows, 0.000 secs]  [Code: 0, SQL State: 44000] 
>   ERROR: new row violates check option for view "myview"   Detail:
>   Failing row contains (11). ... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 rows
>   affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 1 errors]

```
update myview set i=i*10 where i=1;
```

> 19:27:29  [UPDATE - 1 rows, 0.000 secs]  Command processed ... 1
>   statement(s) executed, 1 rows affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000
>   sec  [1 successful, 0 errors]

```
update myview set i=i*10 where i=2;
```

> 19:27:42  [UPDATE - 0 rows, 0.000 secs]  [Code: 0, SQL State: 44000] 
>   ERROR: new row violates check option for view "myview"   Detail:
>   Failing row contains (20). ... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 rows
>   affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 1 errors]